# While using the group _features function of pycaret, how to extract only one stastical information instead of all the the 6 (i want only mean)

Tags: installation, pycaret

s = setup(data, group _features=['','','',......], drop_features =True, group_name = ['','','',....])

The output file has all the six stastical information which I don't require in my ml model.
Output should only show mean of the groups instead of all six stastical information